# How to delete selected chart area in windows form by using C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

I plotted a graph (mschart)and now my question is Clicking Discard button should delete the selected areas and refresh the graph with the remaining.In here user can select multiple chart area.I added multiple selection code also.but I do not know that is correct or not.my interface is like following.
[image: Selection chart area data]

my plotted graph code as follows;

```
private void Output_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            List<Graph> ObservingData = new List<Graph>(); // List to store all available Graph objects from the CSV

            // Loops through each lines in the CSV
            foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(pathToCsv).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
            {
                // here line stands for each line in the csv file

                string[] InCsvLine = line.Split(',');

                // creating an object of type Graph based on the each csv line

                Graph Inst1 = new Graph();


                Inst1.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(InCsvLine[0], dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 

                Inst1.AvE = double.Parse(InCsvLine[15]);
                Inst1.AvI = double.Parse(InCsvLine[16]);

                chart1.Series["Current"].YAxisType = AxisType.Primary;
                chart1.Series["Current"].Points.AddXY(Inst1.AvI, Inst1.AvE);
                chart1.Series["Current"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.FastLine;

                ChartArea CA = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
                CA.AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
                CA.AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = false;
                CA.CursorX.AutoScroll = true;
                CA.CursorX.IsUserSelectionEnabled = true;

            }
        }
```

Following code for my multiple selection for chart area.

```
SizeF curRange = SizeF.Empty;
        List<SizeF> ranges = new List<SizeF>();
        List<int> selectedIndices = new List<int>();

      private void chart1_SelectionRangeChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
            {

                ranges.Add(curRange);
                selectedIndices.Union(collectDataPoints(chart1.Series[0],curRange.Width, curRange.Height)).Distinct();

                StripLine sl = new StripLine();
                sl.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(255, Color.LightSeaGreen);
                sl.IntervalOffset = Math.Min(curRange.Width, curRange.Height);
                sl.StripWidth = Math.Abs(curRange.Height - curRange.Width);
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.StripLines.Add(sl);           

            }
            List<int> collectDataPoints(Series s, double min, double max)
            {
                List<int> hits = new List<int>();
                for (int i = 0; i < s.Points.Count; i++)
                    if (s.Points[i].XValue >= min && s.Points[i].XValue <= max) hits.Add(i);           
                return hits;
            }

      private void chart1_SelectionRangeChanging(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
            {

                curRange = new SizeF((float)e.NewSelectionStart, (float)e.NewSelectionEnd);
            }
```

Please give your kind help to resolve my question.

Comment: Please explain what you want; the question is rather unclear. Yes, it sounds clear but I don't believe that you actually would want to 'discard a ChartArea'. More likely : You want to deletete some DataPoints. If that is what you mean do edit the question. You can delete points just like you add them. Collect those you want to delete in a `List<DataPoint> points` and loop over it: `foreach(var dp in points) series.Points.Remove(dp); - also: the `csv` tag makes no sense, please remove. - Also: The question could do with some code formatting..

Comment: @TaW ,Sir,I want to select some areas and after selecting those area and click the Discard button then should delete those selected area and refresh graph without selected areas.I am newer to this.please give me a path to solve my question.thank you.

Comment: OK, so you want to delete datapoints, right? ((Note Chartarea is a term with a meaning; you have it in your code. If you discard it, nothing can be displayed..)) - So does your selection work and did you try the code I gave you?

Comment: @TaW,sir I edited my question.I want to delete those selected area and clicking after discard button.then want to refresh graph without selected area.Can you give any idea about that.i can not understand where I want to add those code.please any help

Comment: Stop repeating youself! The code obviuosly belongs into the button handler. If I gave you a full answer, chances are you would copy it and post it as an answer like you did last time :-(

Comment: @TaW,ok sir.thank you.I did not paste your answer like my answer.when I did like that,I give my apologize from you. I do not like argue like a biggest person like you. I like to ask a help to solve my coding errors from you because you are an exporter  in this field.I know I am like an idiot.I do not have any person to ask my question.that's why I disturb you sir.pardon me for that.thank you for your help so much .